# fire simulation don't show fire but smoke

Tags: fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation, fire

Im trying to do a fire simulation.  Although I have it as fire on setting Physics property panel, my simulation still showing only smoke.
Can anybody please tell how to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I deleted all particles settings I have created for the mesh and the cube.
- Select the mesh and enable physics for fire direct to the mesh,
- Create a new cube and enable physics as domain.

Done, the fire should appear immediately.

[image]

[image]